# how to use javascript with svg?

Tags: javascript, function, svg

I've tried to put JavaScript into SVG and all are in html file,
when I wrote  as showed in my code my SVG drawing disappear so what is the correct way to write JavaScript so that the SVG will be showed and the function can be applied to it.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <aside>
       height(rx) : <input type="number" name="number" id = "ipheight"
    min ="0" max = "50">
    <input type="button" value="Resize" onclick="resize()">

        <input type="range" id="fthick" min="0" max="10" onchange="thickness()"><br>
                   <input type="radio" name="copies" id="one">One</br>
            <input type="radio" name="copies" id="two">Two</br>
            <input type="radio" name="copies" id="Three">Three</br>
            <input type="radio" name="copies" id="Four">Four</br>
        </aside>
   </body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="500" height="600" 
     viewPort="0 0 1200 1200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<circle cx="315" cy="300" r="15" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"/>
<g id = "first" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(45 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(90 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(135 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(180 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(225 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(270 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(315 315 300)"/> 
<ellipse cx="355" cy="300" rx="25" ry="7" transform="rotate(360 315 300)"/> 
</g>
<g id= "second" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(45 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(45 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(90 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(90 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(135 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(135 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(180 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(180 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(225 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(225 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(270 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(270 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(315 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(315 315 300)"/>
<line x1="380" y1="319" x2="420" y2="300" transform="rotate(360 315 300)"/>
<line x1="420" y1="300" x2="380" y2="280" transform="rotate(360 315 300)"/>
</g>

<g id = "third" style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(45 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(90 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(135 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(180 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(225 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(270 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(315 315 300)"/>
<ellipse cx="390" cy="300" rx="60" ry="20" transform="rotate(360 315 300)"/>
</g>

function resize() {
    var resno = ipheight.value;
        document.getElementById("third").setAttribute("resno");
</script>

</svg>
</html>
```

Comment: You are doing `<script><svg></script></svg>` try fix that.

Comment: Note that an XML declaration (the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` thing) only makes sense in XHTML and mustn't appear in the middle of the document. It may only appear at the very top (i.e. before `<html>` and any `<!DOCTYPE>`).  As you're not using XHTML, simply don't use it.  However, this is not the cause of the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not fully tested the actual script code but if you move the javascript block after the `<svg></svg>` tags like I do in the following:

```
</svg>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resize() {
    var resno = ipheight.value;
        document.getElementById("third").setAttribute("resno");
</script>       
</html>
```

You should see be able to see your image and test your function.